# Jquery video wall mix with Fancybox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I got a code from the internet for a VideoWall, I managed to change it and set everything.

The code is basicly some thumbnails that play the video form archive .mp4 or .ogv with mouse over, and then when click it open a fancybox with video.

The only issue I am having is when I open Vimeo in the Fancybox depending on the browser I am using it will open as flash. The problem is when I try to open it on IOS it will not load, probably cause it is opening as flash..

Here is the code that calls the fancybox

```
<div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/109228610' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/011.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video" data-description="" data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/01.jpg"></div>
```

I know this is must be simple, I don´t know if the information I provided is enought. I need to find a way of making this video open, but not as flash, so IOS devices can see it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is the code

```js
Hello JFK, here is the code i use :

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HTML5 Video Wall</title>
        
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vw_default.css" />
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- fancybox -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
        <!-- end fancybox -->
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.videoWall.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
   var hap_player;  
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    /* SETTINGS */
    var vw_settings = {
     
     /*activePlaylist: Active playlist to start with. enter element 'id' attribute, or leave empty for none. */
     activePlaylist:'playlist1',
     /*playlistList: dom element which holds list of playlists */
     playlistList:'#playlist_list',
     
     /*useLivePreview: true/false (play video on thumbnail rollover). Defaults to false on mobile. */
     useLivePreview:true,
     /*useSound: true/false (use sound in preview videos, if useLivePreview = true) */
     useSound:true,
     /* useWebmVideoFormat: true/false (Browser support for html5 video requires minimum of 2 video formats to cover all browsers, mp4 and ogv being preffered. If useWebmVideoFormat is true, then webm will be used instead of a ogv.) */
     useWebmVideoFormat:false,

     /*wallType: default/icons/zoom/tooltip/'' (''=dont create playlist) */
     wallType:'default',
     
     /*useRemoveButtons: true/false (create button to remove vimeo from playlist; only for wallType icons) */
     useRemoveButtons:true,
     tooltips: {remove: 'Remove',/* remove button */
          expand: 'Expand',/* lightbox button */
          link: 'External link',/* external link button */
          action: 'Custom action'},/* empty action button */
        
     /* media_id: unique id for api (if multiple player instances were used, then strings need to be different!) */
     media_id:'default'
     
    };
    
    hap_player = $('#componentWrapper').videoWall(vw_settings);
    //initApi();
    
   });
   
   var api_panel, api_panel_inited, api_panel_inner, toggle_api_panel, api_panel_opened, tgtime = 300;
   function initApi(){
    
    api_panel = $('#api_panel').css('display', 'block');
    api_panel_inner = $('#api_panel_inner');
    api_panel.css('right', -api_panel_inner.outerWidth(true)-20+'px');
    
    toggle_api_panel = $('.toggle_panel').css({cursor:'pointer', display:'block'}).bind('click', function(){
     if(api_panel_opened){
      api_panel.stop().animate({ 'right': -api_panel_inner.outerWidth(true)-20+'px'},  {duration: tgtime, complete: function(){
       api_panel.css('display','none');
      }});
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('toggle_panel');
      api_panel_opened=false; 
     }else{
      api_panel.css('display','block').stop().animate({ 'right': 41+'px'},  {duration: tgtime});
      $(this).removeClass().addClass('toggle_panel_close');
      api_panel_opened=true;
     }
     return false; 
    }).click();
    api_panel_inited=true;
   }
        
        </script>
         


  

  
    <div id="componentWrapper">
         <div class="componentPlaylist"><div class="playlist_content"></div></div>
         <div class="preloader"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="playlist_list">

    <!-- local tracks -->
    <div id='playlist1'>





           <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/011.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="descriptiions" 
data-description="" data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/01.jpg"></div>
                 
              <!-- 2 think2-->   <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" ' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/012.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/02.ogv'
 data-title="Youtube video" data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/02.jpg"></div>
                 
         <!-- 3 jet -->         <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/013.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/03.jpg"></div>
             
   <!--4 welcome -->         <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/014.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/04.jpg"></div>
                
        <!--5 a linha-->          <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/015.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/05.jpg"></div>

       <!--6 corat -->            <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/016.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/06.jpg"></div>
                                  
          <!--7 pier 111-->           <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/017.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/07.jpg"></div>
                 
             
               <!--8 tarsila -->     <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/018.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/08.jpg"></div>
                 
 <!-- 9 abc dos caes-->     <div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/28383808' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/019.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video Nulla facilisi" 
data-description="descriptiions." data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/09.jpg"></div>
             

             </div>
```

Comment: as far as I know `player.vimeo.com/109228610` should rather be `player.vimeo.com/video/109228610` then fancybox should open it as `iframe` http://jsfiddle.net/o3jxprhk/

Comment: Hello, Thx for the answer JFK, yes I tried that, it should do, but for some reason still opening as flash. i dont know it the class playlistItem may affect this any way either

Comment: is the fiddle opening as flash? what browser?

Comment: Hello, Im not sure what you mean by the fiddle, but using google chrome it opens correctly, when using internet explorer it opens as fash, for that when I open on IOS device (iphone5) it just won´t open so I assume it is also trying to open as flash? Thank you again for the attention.

Comment: For fiddle I referred to this link http://jsfiddle.net/o3jxprhk/ which uses Vimeo's [Universal Player](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding). On another note, iOS (mobile devices) doesn't support flash so videos should normally open on iOS own player, however if you use Universal Player they should play fine on fancybox. IE < 9 will always use flash as fallback since those versions don't support HTML5 video tag.

Comment: I am using the code I sent: 

<div class='playlistItem' data-hook='fancybox-gallery1' data-link='//player.vimeo.com/video/109228610' data-type='local' data-mp4='../media/video/1/wall/011.mp4' data-ogv='../media/video/1/wall/01.ogv' data-title="Vimeo video" data-description="" data-thumb="../media/video/1/wall/01.jpg"></div> 

This will open fine on chrome but it just won´t load on Iphone for example, I am not sure why. Sendint the link of the website might help understand better?
Thankyou

Comment: post your jQuery code (in your question's body) used to initialize fancybox

Comment: posted in 4shared, not sure it thats the code we are looking for, thx for the attention on this matter again.

Comment: I didn't ask for the full html code but the jQuery code where you initialize fancybox (I am not going to download your code, nobody would)

Comment: ok, so can you help me which one of this is the code you are looking for plz. sorry but I am new to this. 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

Comment: none of those, I meant your custom script not the plugin scripts ... something like `$(".fancybox").fancybox({...})`

Comment: Found it, i guess, thank you for the directions, its on the main post.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but I didn't mean any file belonging to the plugin (any file you have downloaded from elsewhere) but the script that you manually have to create to initialize fancybox in your page. I think it would be better if you share a link to your page

Comment: posted up there, sorry to get it wrong again. thats the code I use on my webpage.

Comment: can you share a link? you could create a demo page to reproduce the issue and I guess that would be better (and faster) than digging into your code

Comment: I shared the link JFK, let me know if you have any insights, thanks

Comment: Hey JFK any progress on this? I just can not figure this out. Thank you.